# Reverse Image Search

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

How does a site like Google implement a Reverse Image search? Which part of the image are they searching and how do they 'store' the image data?

I know this is a general question, but am trying to implement a basic 'reverse image search' against 100 images that I have to see if the image 'going in' is already there -- or something similar exists.

Answer (score 3):

Hash the input image file and compare with the hashes of the 100 images already present

Check out this blog post:
https://realpython.com/blog/python/fingerprinting-images-for-near-duplicate-detection/

Comment: Use [Locality-sensitive hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) and compare the bit distance between the 2 image hashes: images that are more similar have fewer differences in thier hashes. In python https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ImageHash